# Aligning text left and right on the same line using HTML inside a QT Html-aware-widget

Tags: python, html, qt, pyside

I'm trying to write a widget to view forum data from a database. I want to align the post's offset in a topic towards the top right on the same line as the user-name meta data. I'm using a QTextEdit and my HTML code building function looks as follows:

```
def draw(self,item):
        post_text = item.post_text.replace("\n","<br /> <br />")
        user_text  = "<b>User:</b> %s. #1<br/>" % item.name
        posted_at = "<b>Posted At</b>: %s." % item.posted_at
        text = user_text + posted_at + "<hr />" + post_text       
        self._text_edit.setText(text)
```

I want the #1 on the right and user on the left. I've tried some `spans`,`divs` and tables with `align` attributes to try and get the thing to work as I want but it does not work. Advice ? :D

p.s., if there are multiple ways to do it, please enumerate them as this will help improve my understanding of manipulating text in QT.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
user_text  = "<b>User:</b> %s. <span style="float:right;">#1</span><br/>" % item.name
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: float and align are different...not sure what your data is wrapped in, but I tried it in a table and a div and the result is the same. Hope you get it working!